# c semaphores and shared memory action counter

Tags: c, shared-memory, semaphore

I am working with semaphores and shared memory. I need create 11 subprocesses. First with I=0 is printing A and others are printing B. Then I need each proces to print message with counter `*APtr` so there will be lines on output with numbers 1-11 followed by proces signification and final value of *APtr on last row which should be 12.

Now its not working. Processes are writing and reading *APtr at the same time so i get output with first numbers for example 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 11, 12

```
int I, A;
int *APtr;
//create shared memory (action counter)
if((A=shmget(ftok(argv[0],getpid()), sizeof(int),  IPC_CREAT | 0660)) == -1)
{
    exit(2);
}
if((APtr=shmat(A,NULL,0)) == NULL)
{
    exit(2);
}
*APtr = 1;


/*semaphor semA*/
sem_t semA;
if(sem_init(&semA, 0, 1)==-1)
{
    exit(2);
}
/*semafor semA*/
pid_t pid;
for(int i=0; i<11; ++i)
{
    if((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {     //chyba spusteni noveho procesu
        kill(0, SIGTERM);
        exit(2);
    }
    else if(pid == 0)
    {
        I=i;
        if(I == 0)//A
        {
            sem_wait(&semA);
            //int pom = *APtr;
            fprintf(stdout, "%d: A %d:\n", *APtr, I);
            fflush(stdout);
            *APtr+=1;
            sem_post(&semA);
        }
        else//B
        {
            sem_wait(&semA);
            //int pom = *APtr;
            fprintf(stdout, "%d: B %d:\n", *APtr, I);
            fflush(stdout);
            *APtr+=1;
            sem_post(&semA);
        }
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        //fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", *APtr);
    }
}
sem_destroy(&semA);
if(pid != 0)
{
    sleep(1);
    fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", *APtr);
}
return 0;
```

If i understand it correctly `sem_init(&semA, 0, 1);` should initialize semaphor to allow only one proces work after `sem_wait(&semA);` until `sem_post(&semA);` command is done. So what am I doing/understanding wrong?

---

After switching to sem_open() i got returnded NULL and all forked processes crash on sem_wait() there is my new code.

```
int I, A;
int *APtr;
//create shared memory (action counter)
if((A=shmget(ftok(argv[0],getpid()), sizeof(int),  IPC_CREAT | 0660)) == -1)
{
    exit(2);
}
if((APtr=shmat(A,NULL,0)) == NULL)
{
    exit(2);
}
*APtr = 1;


/*semaphor semA*/
sem_t *semA;
if(semA = sem_open("/semA", O_CREAT, 0700, 1) == SEM_FAILED)
{
    exit(2);
}
/*semafor semA*/
pid_t pid;
for(int i=0; i<11; ++i)
{
    if((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {     //chyba spusteni noveho procesu
        kill(0, SIGTERM);
        exit(2);
    }
    else if(pid == 0)
    {
        I=i;
        if(I == 0)//A
        {
            sem_wait(semA);
            fprintf(stdout, "%d: A %d:\n", *APtr, I);
            fflush(stdout);
            *APtr+=1;
            sem_post(semA);
        }
        else//B
        {
            sem_wait(semA);
            fprintf(stdout, "%d: B %d:\n", *APtr, I);
            fflush(stdout);
            *APtr+=1;
            sem_post(semA);
        }
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        //fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", *APtr);
    }
}
if(pid != 0)
{
    sleep(1);
    sem_close(semA);
    fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", *APtr);
}
return 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sem_t semA;
if(sem_init(&semA, 0, 1)==-1)
```

Your semaphore here is not in shared memory, it lives on the stack.

So after you fork(), each process will have its own copy of this semahore. You should place the semahore somewhere in the shared memory you've created so all processes can access the same semaphore.

Instead of sem_init() you could use sem_open() to create a named semahore, which are shared among whoever have it opened.

Comment: sem_t *semA;
if(semA = sem_open("/semA", O_CREAT, S_IWGRP | S_IRGRP, 1)== SEM_FAILED)

sem_open fails all the time. :(

Comment: and errno is set to EACCES

Comment: Normally you'd set your user to also read/write the semaphore, e.g. sem_open("/semA", O_CREAT, 0700, 1); , but maybe the semaphore really already exists.

Comment: yep threre is stucked semaphore somewhere... when i renamed it proces continues.

Comment: if(semA = sem_open("/semA123", O_CREAT, 0700, 1) == SEM_FAILED) sets sem_t *semA to 0 so i get sigsegv for each of them except parrent which does not use sem_wait.

Comment: Yes, that statement is broken. You're missing parenthesis,. `if((semA = sem_open("/semA123", O_CREAT, 0700, 1)) == SEM_FAILED)`

Answer (score 0):

It was missing braces:

```
if((semA = sem_open("/semA123", O_CREAT, 0700, 1)) == SEM_FAILED)
```